# Show that the functional is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, holder-inequality

**Task:**

Check if the functional F: $$F(f) = \int_{-1}^1 f(t) sgn(t) dt.$$is continuous on the space $\mathbb E=L_2(-1, 1) $:

**Solution:**

I need to find $M>0$ and show the inequality: $$\vert F(f) \vert \le M (\int_{-1}^1 \vert f(t)\vert^2 dt)^{1/2}.$$

I started from $$ \vert F(f) \vert = \vert \int_{-1}^1 f(t) sgn(t) dt \vert$$

But actually I do not know how to evaluate this function.

I know that somewhere I need to use the **Hölder's inequality**: $$ \int_{-1}^1 \vert f(t) g(t) \vert dt \lt (\vert f(t) \vert^2 dt)^{1/2} (\vert g(t) \vert^2 dt)^{1/2},$$

Comment: What would be $g(t)$ in the Holder inequality?

Comment: I need to find $g(t)$ evaluating the function I started from

Comment: Yes, but for $f(t)\mathrm{sign}(t)$ what $g$ do you take? It's quite obviuous... (And it's  already spoiled in the answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply Hölder with $g=1$, i.e.
$$ \left| \int_{-1}^1 f(t) \, \text{sgn}(t) \, \mathrm dt \right| \leq \int_{-1}^1 |f(t)|\cdot 1 \, \mathrm dt \leq \left(\int_{-1}^1 |f(t)|^2 \, \mathrm dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{-1}^1 1^2 \, \mathrm dt\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt 2\left(\int_{-1}^1 |f(t)|^2 \, \mathrm dt\right)^{1/2}. $$

Comment: That's very helpful for the OP, who didn't even give it a try

Comment: @Federico I read through the question too quickly, it seemed to me at first glance that he/she at least attempted to do something. My bad.